# how to preform a stepwise regression on a LMER model

Tags: r

I have a question about stepwise regression. For a school project i'm using step wise linear regression to select the propper variables for my mixed model in the end. I do first stepwise linear regression and later on add in the mixed model the random effects. However it often happens that the significant variables are not significant anymore when the random effects are added. so my question is how to preform a stepwise regression with random effects included.

i used to next line of code for my stepwise linear regression:(and it works)
`ols_step_both_p(min.swrexMilk.rumi, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1, details = TRUE)`
However when i change `min.swrexMilk.rumi`  which is an LM in a code which is an LMER the code does note work anymore.

Does anybody know which code i need. so that it is possible to select the propper variables, but also taking into account the influence of the random variables directly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Btw in case you aren't aware, stepwise regression is [generally a dangerous way to perform model selection](https://eprint.ncl.ac.uk/file_store/production/56364/AE9762E1-23E2-4C9D-9518-5BCDAD47FAAB.pdf) and isn't really used much any more. Better alternatives like lasso or elastic net regression are used more commonly.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, i will mentoin it in my discusion part however i'm obligated to work with stepwise regession(if it is possible to include the random effects)